Print function not functioning in python
No matter where in my code, if I try and print, my code just errors out with
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
I am trying to make some code that gets an approximation of the width of some crop rows and then cuts the image up into smaller images. OFC im using prints along the way to verify my code is correct. But suddenly no matter where and no matter what I try and print of any variable, I get that same error. I am working in collab and it does this no matter which workspace I type in. It feels like something has broken the print function, specifically having to do with the int part.
the code will not error if the print("hello") is removed
plt.figure(dpi=300)
im2raw=cv2.imread('Problem1.jpg')
c,b,a=cv2.split(im2raw)
im2=cv2.merge([a,b,c])
plt.subplot(231)
plt.imshow(im2)
im=im2
shape=im2.shape
i=0
red=0
for i in range(shape[1]):
  j=0
  for j in range(shape[0]):
    pixel=(im2[j,i])
    b=pixel[2]
    g=pixel[1]
    r=pixel[0]
    if (b>r)or(g>r):
      red+=1
    else:
      im[j,i]=255
    j+=1
  i+=1
plt.subplot(231)
plt.imshow(im)

gray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

ret1,th1 = cv2.threshold(gray,127,255,cv2.THRESH_OTSU + cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
plt.subplot(232)
plt.imshow(th1, cmap = 'gray')

ret2,th2 = cv2.threshold(th1,0,255,cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
plt.subplot(233)
plt.imshow(th2, cmap = 'gray')

blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(th2,(17,17),0)
plt.subplot(234)
plt.imshow(blur, cmap = 'gray')

ret3,th3 = cv2.threshold(blur,0,255,cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
plt.subplot(235)
plt.imshow(th3, cmap = 'gray')
blur2 = cv2.GaussianBlur(th3,(17,17),0)
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(blur2, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = [contour for contour in contours if cv2.contourArea(contour) > 200]
contours = [contour for contour in contours if cv2.contourArea(contour) <10000]
cv2.drawContours(blur2, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 50)
plt.subplot(236)
plt.imshow(blur2, cmap = 'gray')





sh=int(shape[1]/5)
centerlines=[(sh*1)-(sh/2),(sh*2)-(sh/2),(sh*3)-(sh/2),(sh*4)-(sh/2),(sh*5)-(sh/2)]
centerlines=(np.round(centerlines))
centerLines=[int(x) for x in centerlines]
widt=np.zeros(len(centerLines))
i=0
for i in range(len(centerLines)):
  white=False
  j=0
  while white==False:
    pixel=(blur2[20,centerLines[i]+j])
    if pixel==255:
      white=True
    else:
      j+=1
    if (centerLines[i]+j)==shape[1]:
      white=True
  widt[i]=j
  i+=1

print("hello")


Like everything else in python,print is "just a variable".  somewhere, not in the code shown, you're setting print to an integer variable.  Since everything is at the global scope in your program, that changes the value of print for everything.  Use functions.  They make your life easier.

Somewhere in the code you assigned print to be an integer, like print = 7.

I just tested your code, as posted (plus imports for np, plt and cv2). It works without errors, and prints hello. When posting questions, make sure the code you post is a [example]. Your example is neither minimal, nor reproducible.

@erik258 Nitpick: not "everything". while = 7 is an error, as is << = 7. [1, 2, 3] = 7 too. # = 7 is ignored. "all identifiers" though... (Not suggesting you don't know that, but... there's questions like "Is it true that everything is an object", so better be specific about "everything" :) )

Agree that "all identifiers" is a better phrasing.  All your examples, though, are just syntax errors.  If it's not valid python, it falls outside the bounds of "everything in python".  But it's a fair point - keywords like while and for are certainly not "just a variable".
